# CCleaner wrongly detects "Oxygen XML Editor 14"

Tags: windows-7, windows, windows-registry, ccleaner

***CCleaner*** shows amongst the computer applications which can be analyzed in my computer one identified as "***Oxygen XML Editor 14***", although I don't know this software and therefore I've never installed it in my computer.

[image: False positive]

A Windows registry search for this name or part of it returns no result for such software installed in my computer. Piriform (CCleaner manufacturer) doesn't give any satisfactory answer to this problem:
http://forum.piriform.com/index.php?showtopic=38971

What should I do? How do I delete this wrong entry from analyzable applications list in CCleaner?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

***CCleaner*** wrongly identifies (I still don't know why) this registry key:

```
HKCU\Software\ej-technologies
```

as belonging to "***Oxygen XML Editor 14***"

Actually this "false positive" makes reference to any of this three programs:

- JProfiler
- install4j
- exe4j

which are manufactured by [*ej-technologies GmbH*](http://www.ej-technologies.com/index.html)

*install4j* and *exe4j* are known softwares for managing installation and uninstallation of popular Java-based software such as [*DbVisualizer Free*](http://www.dbvis.com/) and [*JDownloader*](http://jdownloader.org/).

[image: install4j wizard]

In the tests I did in my computer, I realized that it is not necessary to complete the installation of software which uses this installer technology: by only starting the installation creates the troublesome registry key.

[image: Registry key after installing DbVisualizer Free]
[image: Registry key after installing JDownloader 2.0 Beta]

I also found that upon uninstalling software which uses this technology it is also created the troublesome registry key and it remains even after successfully completing the uninstallation process.

[image: Registry key after starting uninstall of JDownloader 2.0 Beta]

If none of *ej-technologies* programs (*JProfiler*, *install4j*, *exe4j*) is installed in your computer, and no Java-based software using this kind of installer is installed in your computer, it is safe to delete this registry key, although in any case it is recommended to **always make previously a registry backup**.

Next time you start ***CCleaner***, you will see how "***Oxygen XML Editor 14***" application entry will have disappeared from the Applications list.

[image: CCleaner after removing troublesome registry key]